# About the degeneracy and the time reversal invariant point of Brillouin Zone

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

I'm confusing about some concept of the Band degeneracy in the band theory. As I know the Kramer Theorem guarantee that as long as your system is time reversal invariant and even the Spin orbial coupling present, there is always a 2-fold degeneracy for an electron or fermion. At the high symmetry point of the brillouin zone which is connected by the reciprocal lattice vector has the property of time reversal invariant. Therefore I should expected that there are some degeneracy occur at these points. For a degeneracy to occur, Should I expect that two different bands touch each other at these point. But obviously this is not always the case when we watch the band structure of different material even though it is time reversal invariant. Can anybody tell me where is the mistake in my argument? or this argument only applied to particular cases ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is indeed two-fold invariance. Often, the spin up and spin down bands are identical, so they aren’t necessarily considered separate bands. When they aren’t identical, due to spin-orbit coupling for example, every example I can think of has those bands converging at the high symmetry points (e.g., the $\Gamma$ point, for spin-orbit spilt hole bands in GaAs).

Comment: @Gilbert Thank you for your answer. I agree with you. I want to ask one more question base on this.  Like what you said if we finished some band structure calculation for a system with SOC, can we check our result by examining that whether there is band splitting at the point where is not time reversal invariant and re-converge at the symmetry point again ?